# Texfield on diffrerent page triggers StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter

I have this `StreamBuilder` on Page1:

```
Widget _myFirebaseUser(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData &&
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          print('-loading user2-');
          FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data;
          if (user == null) {
            return Text('not logged in');
          }
          return ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                user.photoUrl,
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(user.displayName),
            subtitle: Text(user.email),
            trailing: new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                highlightColor: Colors.pink,
                onPressed: () {
                   Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/my-set');
                }),
          );
        }
        return Text("loading");
      },
    );
  }
```

On Page2 I have this:

```
TextField(
 controller: inputNewElement,
 decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Add Elements"),
 onSubmitted: (elem) {
  print("Changed textfield");
 },
),
```

When I move to Page2 and edit my TextField I can see the logs from previous page. I have tried `StreamBuilder` and `FutureBuilder` with same result.

How can avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Are you using global keys ??

Comment: I'm just passing some data but not I'm not modifying it at all on Page2 (I updated the `onSubmitted` to make it more clear).
I also tried without passing anything and got the same behaviour